# Remap keys to match Windows, but CMD+Tab for switching app?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I have been using Karabiner and Better Touch Tool to remap my keys, so they match like Windows. Since I'm used to that layout, I wanted it switched. However, since I updated to Sierra, Karabiner no longer works, and I have to use Karabiner Elements, which just can't do multiple keys. So what I have now in Karabiner Elements is:

```
left_command -> left_option
fn -> left command
left_option -> left_control
left_control -> fn
```

This allows me to do stuff like <kbd>Fn</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> for opening a new tab and so on. However, I want to open the Application Switcher (basically <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>) using <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> on the keyboard. In Karabiner I could make a "pass-through", which allowed me to ignore those keys:

[image]

What would the best way be, to satisfy my needs?

Comment: This is the problem with immediately upgrading to a new version of an OS - your stuff that works suddenly doesn't.  According to the folks at Karabiner - it's not compatible with Sierra, but they are working on it.   Aside from finding a whole new solution, I would wait for Karabiner to be compatible with Sierra.

Comment: @Allan Uhm, sure. Karabiner won't be compatible with Sierra. The creator made Karabiner Elements, so he's probably going to disgard Karabiner.

Comment: From the [webpage](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/):  "We'll start updating for the full featured Karabiner for Sierra after Karabiner-Elements is completed."  It's highlighted in the big red box.

Comment: @Allan Oh, that's not what I read on the other sites though. Oh well :-)